# Grouping buttons on XFCE taskbar

Tags: xfce

Good day!
Tell me, please, how to turn off the `grouping` of tabs on the taskbar?
The default looks like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Hold down Control and click on one of the tabs.  This will open up the menu for `Window Buttons` (aka Tasklist).
2. Click on `Properties`.
3. Select "Never" from the `Window grouping` option (in the **Behaviour** section of the dialog)
4. Make a note of how to do this because you'll probably want to re-enable grouping if you ever run an app (e.g. a web browser) with dozens of windows open.