# XFCE how to disable taskbar items grouping

Tags: linux, xfce

I only found one [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105400/how-to-disable-the-grouping-of-windows-on-the-launcher) on this issue from 9 years ago.

I want to disable this so that it displays two terminal items on the taskbar side by side.

[image: grouping taskbar item]

another annoyance with this is that if an app is already open and I open another, it groups it and does not raise the window for that app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping buttons on XFCE taskbar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650721/grouping-buttons-on-xfce-taskbar)

Comment: You can't have searched very hard - I answered the exact same question two weeks ago.

Comment: good question! stupid design!

Answer (score 26):

- Right click on the taskbar, select `Panel` -> `Panel Preferences`
- Select the `Items` tab , select `Window Buttons` in the list, click the `Edit` button on the right side
- Change `Window grouping` to `Never`

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Is there documentation on this sort of thing?

Comment: Sure, you can open the online help by clicking on the `Help` button. Unfortunately, the description of the "Window Buttons" is not helpful at all.

Comment: Um... Allow me to state the obvious: this is not intuitive GUI design. xfce might want to redesign this